# Java Recursion in an If/Else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

I'm trying to figure out why the top block of Code executes but the bottom block of code does not. All I did to get the other to execute was switch the conditions position in my if/else statement

```
public static void onTheWall(int bottles){
    if (bottles == 0){
        System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall,"
                           + " no bottles of beer, ya’ can’t take one down, ya’ can’t pass it around," 
                           + "cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
    } else if (bottles <= 99){
        System.out.println(bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall, " 
                           + bottles + " bottles of beer, ya’ take one"
                           + " down, ya’ pass it around, " 
                           + (bottles - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        onTheWall(bottles-1);
    }
}

public static void onTheWall(int bottles){
    if (bottles <= 99){
        System.out.println(bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall, " 
                           + bottles + " bottles of beer, ya’ take one"
                           + " down, ya’ pass it around, " + (bottles - 1) 
                           + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        onTheWall(bottles-1);
    } else if (bottles == 0){
        System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall," 
                           + " no bottles of beer, ya’ can’t take one down, ya’ can’t pass it around," 
                           + "cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
    }
}
```

Comment: the top one should work, the bottom one will always execute the first if statement

Comment: Zero is less than 99.

Comment: Thank you @JRowan would you happen to know why it will just keep executing the first if statement? If not thank you anyway and I'll do more research.

Comment: because even if bottles is 0, 0 is <= 99, so the first if statement will always execute

Comment: Wow thanks so much everyone that really helped clear that up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switching the conditions `if (bottles <= 99)` and `else if (bottles == 0)` causes the first block to execute because the first condition (bottles <= 99) is true for bottles=0.

If you are expecting the `else if` to execute before the `if` statement, then that is never going to happen.

Maybe your condition should be something like `if (bottles > 0 && bottles <= 99)` in which case your second block will execute if bottles=0 as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void onTheWall(int bottles){
         if (bottles == 0){
                System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall," + " no bottles of beer, ya’ can’t take one down, ya’ can’t pass it around," + "cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
            } else if (bottles <= 99){
                System.out.println(bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + bottles + " bottles of beer, ya’ take one"
                + " down, ya’ pass it around, " + (bottles - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
            onTheWall(bottles-1);
            }
    }
```

Your recursive call does not happen since at the start bottles is 0. Try moving the location of your recursive call or changing the elseif to an if.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with recursion but with the fact that the conditions in the "if" and the "else" are not mutually exclusive.
You can *only* safely switch the order of the "if" and the "else" if the conditions are exclusive. Remember that in an if/elseif chain, only the first matching condition will be executed. If the conditions are not mutually exclusive, the order will matter.

Answer (score 0):

In the second method, the branch `bottles == 0` will never execute.

Because when `bottles == 0`, the `bottles <= 99` is true. It's an infinite recursive loop.